# python: integrated first-order moment of 2D distribution

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics, numerical-integration

I have a (normalized) 2D array of data -- let's say the independent variables are x and theta and the data is Data. (Data is actually a posterior distribution, but just stored as a numpy array.) I need to take the first-order moment over each of the dimensions, i.e. I need to compute the double integrals

[image]

I thought I could implement this as, e.g. for a:

```
firstint = np.trapz(x*Data, dx=dx, axis=1)
a = np.trapz(firstint, dx=dy)
```

where `dx = x[1] - x[0]` and `dy=y[1] - y[0]` (both x and y are 1d arrays of evenly spaced data).

but this doesn't seem to be working -- e.g. when I test it with a 2D gaussian, I would expect to get back the values of (x, y) where the gaussian is peaked, but I don't.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's an MWE, with output below. Note that one of the dimensions (b integral) is working fine. The a integral only gives the expected answer when I set xmeas = 0.5. Am I just not normalizing correctly, or expecting the wrong answer for some other reason?

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import numpy as np

sample_x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
sample_y = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

y_dx = sample_y[1] - sample_y[0]
x_dx = sample_x[1] - sample_x[0]

yarr = sample_y[:, np.newaxis]
xarr = sample_x

# pick some values
ymeas = np.pi/6
xmeas = 0.1

fwhm = 0.3

# construct 2D gaussian
gaussian = np.exp(-4*np.log(2) * ((xarr-xmeas)**2 + (yarr-ymeas)**2) / fwhm**2)

integrated_over_y = np.trapz(gaussian, dx = y_dx, axis = 1)
integrated_over_x_and_y = np.trapz(integrated_over_y, dx = x_dx)

normed_gaussian = gaussian/integrated_over_x_and_y

# y moment
aintegrand = np.trapz(normed_gaussian*sample_x, axis=1, dx=x_dx)
a = np.trapz(aintegrand, dx=y_dx)

print("expected {}, got {}".format(xmeas, a))

# x moment
bintegrand = np.trapz(normed_gaussian*sample_y[:, np.newaxis], axis=1, dx=x_dx)
b = np.trapz(bintegrand, dx=y_dx)

print("expected {}, got {}".format(ymeas, b))
```

Output:

```
>> a: expected 0.1, got 0.147652018282
>> b: expected 0.523598775598, got 0.523610579349
```

Comment: Can you provide the full test you're using? Looks fine to me

Comment: @Eric added an MWE.

Comment: The mean value of a gaussian will be at its center, sure. But you're not working with a gaussian - you're working with a rectangular cut of a gaussian. The further the boundaries are from a value of 0, the less the mean will align with the center of the gaussian. Your code is correct, but your expectation of what should happen is wrong

Comment: Right, of course, thanks.